# Laravel Routing URL with two attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a `City` model and a `Store` model.

A `Store` belongs to a `City` and I would like the URL of a single `Store` to be like:

`/<city-slug>/stores/<store-slug>`

Example:

`/nyc/stores/macys`

This is what I have in the `web.php`:

`Route::get('/{city}/stores/{store}', 'StoresController@show')->name('store');`

The controller:

```
public function show($cityId, $storeId)
{
    $store = \App\Store::where('slug', $storeId)->first();

    return view('stores.show', compact('store'));
}
```

If I access `/nyc/stores/macys` it works but it also works if I replace `nyc` with any other string. I want only the URL with `/nyc/stores/macys` to be working. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: in your query filter is only apply to $storeId not to $cityId. you can apply same for $cityId to restrict it's access

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be because you are only running a query on the store slug. You might try adding another where clause. Since `Store` belongs to `City` maybe try the following:

```
$city = City::where('slug', $cityId)->whereHas('stores', function ($query) use ($storeId) {
     $query->where('slug', $storeId);
})->get();
```

Then if you have a method on your `City` model called `stores` you could access that store data and return something like...

```
return view('stores.show)->with([ 'store' => $city->stores->first() ]);
```

I haven't tested this code myself, but hopefully it might help you.